# Custom rules using Jquery Validate plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I've read all of the Jquery Validate documentation but I'm still not clear on how to have my own custom rules for validating inputs.

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm">
   <input type="text" name="firstName" class="required" />
   <input type="text" name="lastName" class="required" />
   <input type="text" name="phone" class="phone" />
</form>
```

**JQuery/Javascript**

```
$("#myForm").validate({
   rules: {
      // what do I put here so that an input with class phone is validated?
   },
   messages: {
      // what do I put here so that this message is displayed if .phone is invalid?
   }
});
```

From what I've read its possible to build my own rule so that phone number is not only required but its also exactly 10 digits and if it isn't I can specify the message to show.

The JS above is what I've tried essentially straight from the documentation but it doesn't work.  The field is never validated and the message is never displayed.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
rules: {
    name1: {
        required: true,
        ValidCharsGeneral: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 50
    },
    name2: {
        required: true,
        ValidCharsGeneral: true,
        minlength: 2,
        maxlength: 50
    }
},
messages: {
    name1: {
        required: "This information is required",
        minlength: "Username must be at least 6 characters long",
        maxlength: "Username must be at most 50 characters long",
        remote: "Username is already in use"
    },
    name2:{
        required: "This information is required",
        email: "Email address is not valid",
        remote: "Email address is already in use"
    }
}
```

Comment: are id1 and id2 then the classes I would use for the input elements?

Answer (score 1):

There is no default "phone" validator, however the additional-methods.js file contains validators for US and UK phone number patterns. You can find [links to that file here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

You can run this code here: http://jsfiddle.net/iknowkungfoo/XCuPj/

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm">
   <input type="text" name="firstName" class="required" /><br />
   <input type="text" name="lastName" class="required" /><br />
   <input type="text" name="phone" class="phoneUS digits" maxlength="10" /><br />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    messages: {
        phone: "Invalid phone number, please correct this."
    }
});
```

Via the class attributes, I've specified that the **phone** field shoudl match the "phoneUS" and "digits" validation. I've also specified that the "maxlength" for the field is 10. Then, in the JavaScript code, I've specified the message to be displayed when the field names **phone** fails validation.

Alternately, I can specify a message for each validator that is associated with the **phone** field.

**Alternate JavaScript** http://jsfiddle.net/iknowkungfoo/dvfJu/2/

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    messages: {
        phone: {
            phoneUS: "phoneUS failed",
            digits: "digits failed"
        }
    }
});
```

FWIW, if you use the *phoneUS* validator and specify the *maxlength* to 10, then there's no room for dashes between the sections of a phone number. Given that the *phoneUS* validator does not allow alpha-numeric characters (other than a dash), the *digits* validator is unnecessary.

Comment: I appreciate the answer and the tip.  I'll check into this.